# Using struct in action method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, xml-serialization

I want to create object as struct and send it as xml:

```
  def index
   katie = Struct.new(:name, :gender, :age).new("Katie", "F", 18)
   render :xml => katie
  end
```

but I am getting error:

> undefined method `bytesize' for 18:Fixnum

Could somebody give me any advice?

Comment: Any specific reason as to why you would do this?

Comment: Just need example of xml rendering in my uni work. I thought I can use struct instead of ActiveRecord object.

Comment: The rails methods which render xml cannot handle structs. You should switch to using an ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is long after the original question, but here is another answer:

Implement a class using ActiveModel and include serialization support.

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml #also include json
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name, :gender, :age

  def attributes
    {name: name, gender: gender, age: age}
  end
end

#and in your controller
def index  
  # should use a respond_to do |format| here
  render :xml => Person.new(:name => 'Katie', :gender => 'F', :age => 18)
end
```